# Ajustar texto para melhor entendimento

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

Estava lendo na página das eleições, e vi essa caixa de texto a direita:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que deveria ser substituída a parte grifada por

> poderá candidatar-se

ficando a frase completa da seguinte forma:

> Na fase de **indicação**, qualquer membro ativo da comunidade com mais de **300** pontos de reputação poderá candidatar-se a moderador da comunidade.

Não sou do tipo que me apego ao português, mas essa frase me chamou a atenção.